# How do I change provision profile on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I logged in to `developer.apple.com` using my `apple id` then manually created a `provisioning profile` and downloaded it. So far so good. But how do I actually install/use it? The instructions simply tell me to double click the `provisioning profile` file, but when I do nothing happens except that Xcode opens.

If I take a look at the [image: Signing] there is no change under the `provisioning profile` field. It simply says "Xcode Managed Profile". If I go to `preferences` and `account` and press `Download Manual Profiles` nothing happens. Everything looks the same. [image: Here]

In `developer.apple.com` under `Provisioning Profiles` status says active. But if I go to the location of where the file should exist `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/` it's not there. So... how do I get this to work, and how do I even know if it's working? Fell really confused about this...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need to uncheck the "Automatically manage signing" checkbox.  Also, when you double-click the .mobileprovision file, it will open Xcode and install the mobileprovision file in the location you mentioned, but it will change the name, so it is likely there, but has been renamed by Xcode.  If you want to keep the file name in tact, you can simply copy the .mobileprovision file into that directory manually to install it for use in Xcode.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! Guess It worked this whole time, but I was confused by it renaming itself :)